# Canadian study permit refusal

Tags: canada, student-visa, study

I am a citizen of country 'P'(in South Asia), applied from the country 'Q'(in EU) where I was studying.

> Previous refusal (2017) disclosed and noted. PA (34), married with one
>   minor child intend to study in Canada at 'X' University in a
>   MSc in 'Y'. Letter of
>   representative noted on file. University letter for IRCC showed unpaid
>   fees for the first academic year. Statutory declaration of PA's father to
>   financially support his son while in Canada. According to PA's
>   statement of purpose, he was refused at multiple universities in 2014
>   and 2017 for continuing his academic progression and already has a
>   full-time employment offer from a private university in 'Z'. I
>   have concerns regarding the purpose of travel, length of stay,
>   immigration status in country of residence, employment prospects in
>   country of residence, family ties in country of residence and
>   financial abilities to support study program. Previous officer
>   concerns remains. I am not satisfied the applicant is a BF temporary
>   resident in Canada and that she would leave Canada at the end of the
>   authorized stay. Application refused.

1. Embassy says I didn't pay my tuition fees when University directed me to pay tuition fee after obtaining Visa.
2. Embassy says I am not a BF student - when I am doing a research in a university in the country from where I have applied for the Visa.
3. The embassy says my financial ability is unsure - when I supplied appropriate financial evidence which they didn't like.
4. They say they are unsure about my family ties - I am married with a child. I supplied the marriage certificate and birth certificate of the child.
5. they say I was refused in multiple universities when I was accepted in a last university where I am studying to do a graduate research and I am still a bona fide and running student.

What is going on actually?

Comment: In your bullet points, you're bring up several issues that aren't in the refusal text that you quoted. Did you omit some of the refusal notice (we need to see all of it) or was some of that information given to you during an interview?

Comment: @mkennedy, no. This is the entire notice I obtained from Ottawa through right to access to information.

Comment: @mkennedy, I supplied papers regarding what I said in bulletted points.

Answer (score 2):

I"m going to do some speculation.

You applied to multiple universities in 2014 and 2017 before getting accepted so you're not a prime candidate. You're also coming across as very eager (desperate) to get into Canada since you've had a prior refusal.

Stating that you have a job offer in your current country of residence may have backfired. If you're willing and/or looking for a job there, you'll probably look for a job in Canada as well and abandon your studies or work illegally.

Comment: If you think in this way, no one in this earth is supposed to get a visa.

Comment: The job offer is conditional. It says, I need to have a research degree to avail the job. Apparently, they didn't pay attention to the language.